# Why autocomplete not always working

Tags: ros, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sometimes it works sometimes not...

i am learning how to create a package using ROS tools, autocomplete is one of the most gentle features...

but sometimes I do:

> rosclient@rosclient-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun bos

looking for a autocomplete in my new package name bosca but not always working..

why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258347/why-autocomplete-not-always-working/) by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 424 on 2017-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometimes ROS doesn't always find newly added packages. From the root of your workspace, try running

```
rospack profile
```

and see if that helps by running

```
rospack find
```

or any command that failed earlier.

Source: http://wiki.ros.org/rospack/Troubleshooting#rospack_is_unable_to_find_packages_that_are_added_recently

Edit:

I can confirm that (at least for me) that this method works. I just installed a new package and it was not found by ROS using the tab auto-complete. I followed the instructions in this answer and now tab auto-complete works.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on 2017-04-05**:
Thanks!!! @jayess

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-04-05**:
No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you always run source devel/setup.*sh in same session before trying autocomplete?

---

Originally posted by [7wLH](https://answers.ros.org/users/29890/7wlh/) with karma: 11 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sometimes happens to me as well, even if I correctly source the devel/setup.*sh. If I first manually enter the package I have just created, then autocomplete works.

Some other times autocomplete throws an error like in [Permission denied: .gvfs](http://answers.ros.org/question/76896/permission-denied-gvfs/) . It seems that you are using a virtual machine and the .gvfs is a virtual file extension, maybe it's related.

---

Originally posted by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) with karma: 74 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1